# Pass params in tRestClient Talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I'm trying to pass params to a tRestClient but it's not taking this params :

[image]
Any help please ?
Thx

Comment: Where do your params come from ? And how are you trying to pass them in your exemple ?

Comment: Hello @iMezouar , I'm reading Sharepoint Online Lists I use params like "filter , top or select " to filter data and when I pass them in the URL evry thing works fine but when I use "params of the query" (as shown in my screenshot )TRestClient dont take them

Comment: For Sharepoint, I think that you need to prefix the parameter names with $, ex. $filter, $select